# How to update matplotlib.widgets.TextBox?

Tags: python, matplotlib, textbox, event-handling, widget

I have `matplotlib` graph with `TextBox`. Now I would like to update textbox data `on_press` event. How can I do that? Please have a look ...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import TextBox

def main(datax, datay):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.15)
    line, = ax.plot(datax, datay)        
    textBox()        //textbox
    cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', on_press) // update textbox data here       
    plt.show()

def on_press(event):
    print('you pressed', event.button, event.xdata, event.ydata)

def textBox(text=''):
    axbox = plt.axes([0.125, 0.01, 0.775, 0.075])
    text_box = TextBox(axbox, '', initial=text)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(datax, datay)
```